# Why is Coverity Scan stopping abruptly in my Travis CI build with no error message

Tags: travis-ci, coverity

My Travis CI build invokes Coverity Scan, which terminates abruptly with no error message. The last two lines of output are

```
Coverity Scan analysis selected for branch master.
Coverity Scan API a
```

The Travis CI build then error-terminates.

Here is the [complete output from my latest Travis CI build](https://travis-ci.org/Unidata/LDM/builds/525148826).

And here is my [.travis.yml file](https://github.com/Unidata/LDM/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You appear to have solved the issue in Unidata LDM [v6.13.11.60](https://travis-ci.org/Unidata/LDM/builds/526653553?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification). What [change](https://github.com/Unidata/LDM/compare/3bea79fbe8e4...2cdf70f59f9c) fixed the problem?

Comment: The problem was the value of the COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, apparently. The "secure: ..." entry shown on the "Submit Build" -> "Configure Travis CI" webpage didn't work, so I deleted that entry from my ".travis.yml" file and, instead, copied the unencrypted value shown on that page and pasted it into the value for the environment variable "COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN" in the "Settings" page for the project on Travis CI.